# I am cooking beef stew in the crockpot and accidentally put a little flour in the beginning not end

Tags: flour, crockpot

I am cooking a beef stew in the crockpot and instead of adding a little flour at the end I accidentally added it at the beginning. What do I do to fix this? Will it mess the stew up? There was extra broth so will it just not thicken and still cook ok?

Comment: If it's not breaking apart, you can use a cheap, coarse, colander to take care of the little flour chunks. If you're adding any tallow or butter to the stew, an easy trick is to [make a roux](https://thegourmandmom.com/2010/06/29/how-to-make-a-roux/) with the flour first, **then** add it to the stew. By making a roux, each small bit of flour is effectively encased in a layer of yummy fatty goodness. Once you add some water or milk, it's nearly impossible for the flour to clump. Add it to the stew, and you're home-free. Best of luck!

Answer (score 20):

You should be fine, as long as you mix it in thoroughly.

Flouring the beef and browning is a very common first step, so there is maybe some in there already? Any extra flour to thicken needs some time to cook or it will make the gravy feel grainy.

Stir, stir, stir, and if you see any lumps, take them out. Be careful that this does not over-thicken the broth, as that might stick and burn during the simmering time that makes stew so stewy.